# Javascript time manipulation retrieving hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, time

I made a countdown checking for hours for my website. I would like to change my check which is actually pretty basic to check not only hours but minutes too.

```
var currentHour = new Date().getHours();
if (currentHour >= 9 && currentHour <= 12) { do whatever }
```

I would like to check not between 9h and 12h but between 9h30 and 12h30.

I can't find a way to do this with JS (i started JS yesterday but i have exp in other languages).

My first idea was to use Date() with prototype parameters to retrieve hours and minutes like this :

- it is 12h30, date return = 1230

But can't find a way to do this and i'm sure there is another simple way to do this.

Comment: Have a look - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getminutes.asp

Comment: You can try `hr= date.getHours(); min = date.getMins(); if ( hr > 9 && hr< 12 || hr === 12 && min === 0 ) { /* Put your code here */ }`

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky Hi, thanks for answering. Unfortunately i already understood how to get minutes, my issue is how to compare hours+minutes without doing 2 or 3 if conditions.
I would like to use Date() in a way to compare current time in hours and minutes against 12h30 for example.

Comment: @Rajesh thanks but if (hr > 9 && hr < 12) validate (for example it is 9h30) there is no minutes handling and the condition validate without checking for the "|| hr === 12 && min === 0 "right ? What if i dont want the condition to validate if it is <9h30

Comment: @nihi can you please document the validation's sudo code? It would be easier for us to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var today = new Date()

var startDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 9, 30, 0).getTime();
var endDate = new  Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 16, 30, 0).getTime();

console.log(today.getTime()>startDate&&today.getTime()<endDate)
```

Comment: @nihi can you please accept my answer if it solve your requirement

Answer (score 0):

i think you could do something like this

```
const startDate = new Date('month day, year 09:30:00');
const endDate = new Date('month day, year 12:30:00');
var currentDate = new Date(your date);

if(currentDate > startDate && currentDate < endDate){
your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Xiko that could fit but i prefer Shiva Sai way